# What's the difference pass reference type by value and normal method

Tags: c#

I've been working for the methods, and i found that there is ways to massage the list of object i have. It makes me to think, what is the difference between normal method and pass by reference.

Is there any performance difference or just the same?

here is the sample code

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
}

 public string MainFunction()
    {
        var sampleClassesList = new List<SampleClass>
        {
            new SampleClass
            {
                FirstNumber = 1,
                SecondNumber = 2
            },
            new SampleClass
            {
                FirstNumber = 3,
                SecondNumber = 4
            }
        };

        //Way 1 - return result
        sampleClassesList = Calculate1(sampleClassesList);

        //Way 2 - pass a reference type by value
        Calculate2(sampleClassesList);

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public List<SampleClass> Calculate1(List<SampleClass> sampleClasses)
    {
        foreach (var item in sampleClasses)
        {
            item.FirstNumber += item.FirstNumber;
            item.SecondNumber -= item.SecondNumber; 
        }
        return sampleClasses;
    }

    public void Calculate2(List<SampleClass> sampleClasses)
    {
        foreach (var item in sampleClasses)
        {
            item.FirstNumber += item.FirstNumber;
            item.SecondNumber -= item.SecondNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Way 2 - pass a reference type by value"* - Well, "Way 1" is doing the exact same thing. The fact that it returns the same list (or anything, really) doesn't change the fact that the parameters are passed exactly the same way. There's no difference to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Calculate2() one because not only is it common design pattern but you can also change "List" to "IEnumerable" and then you can also pass arrays or any kind of collection to the method.